# What the difference between the output of kill -l on Bash and Zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, kill

[image: kill -l output]

When I run the `kill -l` command in Zsh and Bash, the results are different. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use `which` command

as can be seen below, those are different implementation of kill. zsh uses an internal one.

zsh:

```
~ % which kill
kill: shell built-in command
```

bash:

```
~$ which kill
/bin/kill
```